# How much time does it take to circularize a GTO orbit using ion propulsion?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, propulsion, communication-satellite

SpaceX launched two GEO comsats, and is about to launch two more, that use all-electric ion propulsion.

Now, I'm wondering, how much time would it take to actually make a satellite like that operational. After all, while ion propulsion is cool and lightweight, it has a very, very low thrust. ([Eutelsat 117 West B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutelsat_115_West_B) apparently has only about 200 mN — that's *millinewtons* — of thrust)

Obviously I can just look it up for an operational satellite, but would be interested in calculating the answer for any arbitrary satellite.

Answer (score 10):

I'm taking Eutelsat 117 W B as an example.

The simple, obvious answer is "about half a year" — this satellite was launched in March and entered service in October 2015.

But I wanted to figure out the answer with physics and come up with roughly the same answer:

The satellite has a mass of `m = 2200 kg` and thrust of `T = 0.2N`. It takes about `dv = 1.6 km/s` to circularize the orbit from GTO to GEO.

Therefore, we need a change of momentum of:

`dp = m * dv = 1.6 km/s * 2200kg = 3.52 * 10^6 kg m/s`

to achieve our final orbit. Since change in momentum is equivalent to impulse:

`dp = J = T * t`

we can calculate the time it takes, with our tiny thrust, to achieve that impulse:

`t = dp / T = 3.52 * 10^6 / 0.2 = 1.76 * 10^7 s = 204 days`

204 days is about 6 months and 3 weeks.

Comment: At least that seems to make sense to me — so I wanted to share my numbers, but I don't know if I'm not oversimplifying something. So if my physics is wrong, I'd love to hear how to properly calculate that for any satellite.

Comment: Possible oversimplifications: Eutelsat 117 West B is not actually in GEO (its orbit is not circular), so your `dv` might be off. And of course `m` is not constant, but decreasing through the “burn”, so you would have to figure out how much reaction mass is used, then solve a differential equation to get an even-more-accurate value.

Comment: I've added [a related question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/16604/12102).

Comment: It's always okay to accept your own answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: is that assuming it can burn the whole time instead of just when it's near the highest point?