# What's the lowest altitude that an ion engine has been used for a significant orbital maneuver?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, electric-propulsion, very-low-earth-orbit

I'm thinking about trying to calculate something for [Where do ion propulsion's ions go? Do they remain in the solar system or shoot out into interstellar space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34441/12102)

Excluding low altitude tests of ion propulsion ([Will the ISS have electric propulsion to maintain altitude? Is there enough power for it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19816/12102)), what is the lowest orbit or altitude where an ion engine has been used to generate a significant orbital maneuver?

Modern "all electric" GEO satellites do use electric propulsion to get to GEO as well as for station-keeping, but I am not sure if that orbit raising stars from circular LEO or the spacecraft is given a partial or full GTO boost first. [How much time does it take to circularize a GTO orbit using ion propulsion?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16588/12102). Same with SMART-1: [Going from LEO to lunar using only low-thrust ion propulsion - can it be done?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28037/12102)

"Lowest orbit or altitude" is a little tricky, one case may have the lowest semimajor axis, another may have the lowest perigee, a third may have the lowest altitude at the time the engine was started. My primary interest is **lowest altitude** but other answers are interesting and may suffice if there's incomplete data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JAXA's [Tsubame](http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/sat/slats/) satellite is planned to orbit to altitudes as low as 180 km, using an ion engine to reboost. It was [launched in January 2018](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2157447-japan-launches-super-low-orbit-satellite-to-test-ion-engines/) into an initial orbit at ~480 km, its orbit will be gradually lowered over a period of 2 years.

> The Super Low Altitude Test Satellite "TSUBAME" (SLATS) is the first Earth observation satellite to use a super low orbit.
>
> SLATS will use the ion engine technology developed by JAXA in order to verify its technology for orbit control at super low altitudes.
> The test satellite will also collect technical data related to the atmosphere, which will be used in the design of future satellites.
> Furthermore, SLATS will photograph the Earth, and its technology will be evaluated for future Earth observation satellites.

Comment: Thanks, I also found [this pdf](http://global.jaxa.jp/activity/pr/brochure/files/sat37.pdf)  I'm also hoping to hear about an ion maneuver to make a significant change in an orbit as well.